# Drupal 7 get teaser with field_view_value()

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, teaser

I have an Ajax handler script where I load a `$nodeId` and output the result in default (full) view:

```
$node = node_load($input);
$prerendered_node = node_view( $node, 'default' );
...
```

Now I need to display the teaser (summary or trimmed) as well.

I tried this so far, without success (summary is filled in content):

```
1.
$item = $node->body['en'][0];
$output = field_view_value('node', $node, 'body', $item, 'Teaser');
echo $output; (blank)

2. echo $node->body['eng']['0']['summary']; (blank)
```

A solution from [this](http://drupal%20node_load%20and%20teaser%20problem) question but not working:

```
3. $output = truncate_utf8(strip_tags($node->body['eng']['0']['summary']),200,true,true);
echo $output; (blank)
```

Curious is that `var_dump($node->body['eng']['0'])` displays and array containing `value` (of body), `summary`, `clean_summary` and other elements and the `summary` has the necessary value filled. But as in example 2 I can't directly access it, it's coming up blank on display.

Tips, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess this a multi-lingual site otherwise you'd probably find what you were looking for in `$node->body['und'][0]` (i.e. `und`, the undefined language code)?

Your 1st solution should work, only you've used `Teaser` instead of `teaser`, I'm pretty sure the view mode is case sensitive. Also you've got `$node->body['en'][0]` (language code of `en`) whereas you've used the language code `eng` in all of the other examples...could that be the problem?

Your 2nd solution would simply have to work if `$node->body['eng']['0']['summary']` was not empty so I'd check again that your `var_dump()` is producing accurate results (are you inspecting the output of `var_dump()` immediately after you call `$node = node_load($input);` to make it a fair test, for example).

Similarly if your 3rd solution is outputting a blank string it means `$node->body['eng']['0']['summary']` absolutely must be empty.

I'd strongly recommend installing the [devel module](http://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and using the `dpm()` function to print a nicely formatted, hierarchical view of objects/arrays for inspection. If you can't do that Drupal 7 has a `debug()` function which does something similar. The output of both of these functions is printed to the standard Drupal message space.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer, that helped me.<br/> First of all I fixed the typos with `eng` and `en` in the question (in code they are fine).<br/> All solutions stated above work fine, except solution 1 where I had to change from `Teaser` to `teaser`, but I was echoing in the wrong place. After I changed the place where I dump the data, it started working.

Answer (score 10):

The correct way to do this without accessing the value directly (so you automatically get an internationalised version I think) is shown below:

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$body = field_get_items('node', $node, 'body');
$teaser = field_view_value('node', $node, 'body', $body[0],'teaser');
```

To output the $teaser value, you need to pass it to the render() function

```
print render($teaser);
```

JC

Comment: Gr8 answer. +1 for simplicity and straight forward answer.